# how to get class using embed tag from a library project in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I created a library project, which contains an embed image like below in class `AssetLib`.

```
   [Embed(source="Frame_Title_BG.png")]
   private var Frame_Title_BG:Class;
```

then I exported the swc to my existing actionscript project.So i assume that the img
`Frame_Title_BG` should be in the memoroy，but when i try to created the class

```
var assetCLs:Class = getClassByAlias('Frame_Title_BG');
var asset = new  assetCLs();
```

I was not able to get the `assetCLs`;

In my mind, all the class should be in the applicationDomain.

So  how can i use the Class in my current project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add "ClassHolder_" before the embed class name:

```
    var imageClass:Class= ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition('AssetLib_Frame_Title_BG') as Class;
    var bitmap:DisplayObject = new imageClass();
    addChild(bitmap);
```

Comment: hi,thx for the answer, seems flash do has the img class, but the return value is an object,not an bitmap class, i still not being able to add it to the stage,i think i shouldn't do this by this method,im i right?

Comment: the _getDefinition_ method return Class, you can create instance with the _new_ operator, I updated my answer for the usage

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can define the asset as a public static variable, then you should be able to do the following:

```
public class AssetLib
{
    [Embed(source="Frame_Title_BG.png")]
    public static var Frame_Title_BG:Class;
}
```

Then in another class:

```
var frameBG:Bitmap = new AssetLib.Frame_Title_BG() as Bitmap;
addChild( frameBG );
```

or even

```
var frameBG:Bitmap = new AssetLib['Frame_Title_BG']() as Bitmap;
addChild( frameBG );
```

Just another option.